# how work thread in tcp listner in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I try to understand how threads work when I use tcpListenner in c# , I have this code :

```
public void threadListenner()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    TcpListener tcpListenner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, tcpPort);
    tcpListenner.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Socket handlerSocket = tcpListenner.AcceptSocket();

        if (handlerSocket.Connected)
        {
            //textBox1.Text += handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "::" + "Connected\n";
            lock (this)
            {
                allsockets.Add(handlerSocket);
            }
            ThreadStart thdsHandler = new ThreadStart(handlerThread);
            Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdsHandler);
            thdHandler.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thdHandler.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is if the server Receive 3 request in the same time How much "thdHandler" great 3 or 1 ?? I see while loop so I think it 3 is it true ?

Comment: It should start a new thread for each connection you receive. Just a note, look at Tasks and async/await to replace you ThreadStart code.

Comment: Please don't ever do `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`. There's a reason these calls are called "illegal".

Comment: Also, don't do `lock (this)` - any external code could also lock on the instance of `this` which then can dead-lock your code.